# Does clean install remove non-standard root directories?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I need to clean install Ubuntu 12.04 and I understand that this will remove everything that was in the `/home` directory. In addition to standard folders such as `/var`, `/etc`, `/usr` and the such, let's say I have other directories such as:

1. `/backup` and `/backup2` which are empty unless I mount the corresponding hard drives. So it wouldn't be too much of a problem if the folders are deleted, I'll just re-create them and mount the disks.
2. `/others` which contains some documents (don't ask me why it's there);

Would non-standard folders like `/others` disappear upon clean install, or will the system ignore folders that do not seem relevant to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will remove only system directories if you will install it on non-formatted drive. More, the `/etc/apt/sources.list` will be untouched and everything in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` will be removed. Also, `/usr/local` will be left untouched in this process.

But *Clean Install* option, AFAIK, actually formats the drive, so your docs and folders on `/` will be lost.